# What is Sri Rama Taraka Mantra?

Tags: shiva, rama, identification-request, parvati

Some information about Sri Rama Taraka Mantra [from Drik Panchang site](https://www.drikpanchang.com/vedic-mantra/gods/lord-rama/mantra/rama-taraka-mantra.html)

> Taraka Mantra is a popular Mantra among devotees of Lord Rama. Taraka Mantra is Trayodasha Akshari Mantra which consists of 13 syllabuses. As the name Taraka suggests, it is believed that chanting Taraka Mantra liberates the person from the cycle of the birth and death.
>
> Taraka Mantra was first revealed to Goddess Parvati by Lord Shiva. While imparting Taraka Mantra to His spouse Lord Shiva mentioned that chanting Taraka Mantra is equivalent to chanting Sahasranama i.e. 1000 names of Lord Vishnu.

Some say it's name of Lord Rama

> राम
>
> Rama

Some say it's name of Lord Rama thrice

> राम राम राम
>
> Rama Rama Rama

[Others say its the thirteen syllables mantra](https://www.drikpanchang.com/vedic-mantra/gods/lord-rama/mantra/rama-taraka-mantra.html)

> श्री राम जय राम जय जय राम
>
> Sri Rama Jaya Rama Jaya Jaya Rama

I want know what exactly is Sri Rama Taraka Mantra also what are the sources for this mantra. In which scripture there is reference for the story of Lord Shiva revealing this mantra to Maa Paravati.

Answer (score 1):

Ram- 1st Tarak mantra of bhagwan shri Ramchandra that is chanted by mahadev himself in Kashi

1.
**रामनाम्ना शिव काश्यां भुत्वा पूत शिव स्वयम्।
स निस्तारयते जीवराशीन् काशीश्वर सदा।।**
Shiv samhita 2.18

Shiv himself gives Tarak mantra “ram” to those jivas who didn’t get moksh in Kashi.

2.
**रामेति नाममात्रस्य प्रभावभति दुर्गम्।
मृगयन्ति ते तद्वेढाः कुतो मंत्रस्य ते प्रभो।।**
Mahasambhu samhita

Even all of the Vedas can’t sing all the glories of shri ram naam. And there is no such devas or anyone else who can say full importance of ram naam.

3.
**अहं भवन् नामगृणन्कुतार्थो वसामि काश्यामनिशं भवान्या।
मुमूर्षमाणस्य विमुक्तोऽहं दिशामि मंत्रो तव रामनाम ।।**
Adhyatm ramayan 6.15.62

Shiv says: I always chant ram naam while  residing in Kashi. There I use to give Tarak mantra ram ram to dying person…

4.
**उपदिशाम्यहं काश्यां तेऽन्तकाले नृणां श्रुतौ।
रामेति तारकं मंत्र तमेव विद्धि पार्वती।।**
Anand Ramayan yatra khand 2.15,-16

Shiv says that he always ram naam while residing in Kashi and starts giving advice of taraak mantra “ram” in Kashi.

5.
**तत्रोत् क्रमणकाले तु साक्षाद् विश्वेश्वरः स्वयम्।
व्याचष्टे तारकं ब्रह्म येनासौ तन्मयो भवेत्।।**
Skandpuran 4.1.25.73

When the soul comes out of the body, then mahadev himself gives Tarak Brahm “ram” to the dying person.

6.
**यत्र साक्षान् महादेवो देहांते स्वयम् ईश्वरः।
व्याचष्टे तारकं ब्रह्म तत्र एव ह्यविमुक्तये।।**
Padmapuran 3.33.47

Mahadev who is himself ishwar gives Tarak mantra “ram” at the time of death while residing in Kashi

7.
**यत्र साक्षान् महादेवो देहांते स्वयम् ईश्वरः।
व्याचष्टे तारकं ब्रह्म तत्र एव ह्यविमुक्तये।।**
Kurma puran 1.31.61

Mahadev who is himself ishwar gives Tarak mantra “ram” at the time of death while residing in Kashi

Next Tarak mantra
Shri Ram jai Ram Jai Jai Ram

**मंत्रा नानाविधाः सन्ति शतशो राघवस्य च। तेभ्यस्त्वेकं वदाम्यद्य तव मंत्रं युधिष्ठिर।।४४ श्रीशब्धमाद्य जयशब्दमध्यं जयद्वेयेनापि पुनः प्रयुक्तम्। त्रिःसप्तकृत्वो रघुनाथनामजपो निहन्याद्द्विजकोटिहत्याः।।४५**

(Anand ramayan Manohar khand)

There are many mantras related to bhagwan shri Ram that you can write, chant. If chanting use Tulsi mala but chant should be in 1 lakh or 1 crore. At first shri Ram, in middle use jai Ram and in end, jai jai Ram ( shri ram jai ram jai jai ram ). This mantra when chanted crore times can get rid of crore times of brahma hatya.

Comment: the verses quoted here are from which purana/scripture text?

Comment: Shiva samhita is narad pancharatra text

Comment: Thanks. Do you have link to the verse on Shiva Samhita please?

Comment: References 5, 6 and 7 above do not mention Rama Nama. instead it says Taraka Mantra, which has been discussed in this site already as Pranava.